# How to convert DataFrame to array of integers while also omitting nan values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `DataFrame` having 3 columns.

```
A  B  C
-------
1  2  4
2  3  nan
4  4  2
```

I need to convert this to a numpy array of integers and omit the `nan` values.

So I need this:

```
[ [1 2 4],
  [2 3 4],
  [4 2] ]
```

How do I do this? I specifically need the elements in the resultant array to be integers and omit the `nan` values.

Comment: NumPy does not support jagged arrays.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
In [11]: [[int(i) for i in r if not np.isnan(i)] for _, r in df.iterrows()]
Out[11]: [[1, 2, 4], [2, 3], [4, 4, 2]]

In [12]: [[int(i) for i in r if not np.isnan(i)] for _, r in df.iteritems()]
Out[12]: [[1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [4, 2]]
```